# Как реализовать класс one который хранит все методы?

Tags: c#, winforms, классы, методы

Но видимо проблема с передачей конструкторов я думаю

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private one clasone;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class one //основний для роботи з массивами символів
    {
        private DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private TextBox textBox1;
        public int check = 0;
        public double[] Array = new double[0];
        public one(DataGridView dataGridView1, double[] array, TextBox textbox1)
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = dataGridView1;
            this.Array = array;
            this.textBox1 = textbox1;
        }
        private bool Check()
        {
            if (check != 0)
                return true;
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not enough values!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        public void BubbleSort()
        {
            if (Check() == true)
            {
                
                double temp;
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Array.Length - 1 - i; j++)
                    {
                        if (Array[i] > Array[j + 1])
                        {
                            temp = Array[j];
                            Array[j] = Array[j + 1];
                            Array[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += (Array[i].ToString() + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        public Tuple<double, double> MinMax()
        {
            if (Check() == true)
            {
                textBox1.Visible = true; textBox1.Clear();
                double min = Array.Min();
                double max = Array.Max();
                textBox1.Text = "Min= " + min + " Max= " + max;
                return (Tuple.Create(min, max));
            }
            else
            {
                double a = 0;
                return (Tuple.Create(a, a));
            }

        }
        public void Ave()
        {
            if (Check() == true)
            {
                
                textBox1.Text += ("С: " + Array.Average());
            }
        }
        public void ParOrNot()
        {
            if (Check() == true)
            {
                
                for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
                {
                    double Par, Not, ParNotPar;
                    if ((Array[i] % 2) == 0 && (Array[i] != 0))
                    {
                        Par = Array[i];
                        dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = Par; //richTextBox1.Text += "Par=" + " " + Par;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (Array[i] % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        Not = Array[i];
                        dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[2].Value = Not;//richTextBox1.Text += "Not=" + " " + Not;
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (Array[i] == 0)
                    {
                        ParNotPar = Array[i];
                        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = ParNotPar;
                        n++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Перезаписать";
        int SumCell = 0;
        bool indic = true;
        var _listOfTrad = new List<double>();

        for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                _listOfTrad.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[0, a].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                indic = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++) //кол-значний в dataGrid
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; y++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[y, i].Value != null)
                {
                    SumCell = SumCell + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        clasone.check = SumCell;

        if (indic == true)
        {
            double[] array = new double[SumCell];
            array = _listOfTrad.ToArray();
            clasone = new one(dataGridView1, array, textBox1);
        }
        else if (indic == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough values!");
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clasone.check != 0) {
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "Sort")
                {
                    clasone.BubbleSort();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.Text == "MinMax")
                {
                    clasone.MinMax();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.Text == "Average")
                {
                    clasone.Ave();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.Text == "PairUnpair")
                {
                    clasone.ParOrNot();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Саму ошибку не компилятор не находит а просто выбивает предупреждение. Пребпологаю что я неправильно реализовал конструкторы textBox, dataGridView в классе one

Comment: Проблема то в чем заключается?

Comment: @tym32167 В передачи временного массива array из button_click1 в класс one

Comment: У вас внутри класса `One` все методы зависимы от объектов `DataGridView dataGridView1, double[] array, TextBox textbox1`, которые вы просите через конструктор, ок, но в тот-же самый момент, вы делаете пустой конструктор, и создаете объект через него, не передавая внутрь каких либо значений. Уберите `public one() { }` и создайте класс как положено, один раз, используя его везде, где положено. А то вот к примеру, берем эту строку `One.BubbleSort();`, сам `One` это `one One = new one();` (класс без указания параметров), а в методе вы делаете `textBox1.Clear();`, где `textBox1 == null`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ рядом, но не совсем

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тоесть нужно использовать одну переменную типа one - например One и проверить недопускать чтоб textBox1 был null?

Comment: @XARiN Нужно сделать класс, который будет иметь все зависимости, без всяких проверок и прочего. Вот просто спроецируйте это на реальный мир, например, человек, вот для его существования, у человека должно быть сердце, легкие, мозг, и так далее, это все внутренние его объекты, необходимые для правильной его работы. Также и ваш класс, для его правильной работы, в вашем коде, требуется обязательно наличие `DataGridView`, `array` и `textbox1`, без них код не будет работать так, как надо. Вопрос тогда, зачем создавать класс без этих данных? Зачем пустой конструктор? Да и зачем два объекта `one`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну вот просто этот момент я и не понимаю. Как сделать чтоб эти элементы DataGridView. array и textbox1 были в этом классе (такое задание у меня просто!). Попробовал оставить один обьект One но серовно значения не передаются в массив Array

Comment: Вы ведь делали уже `new one(dataGridView1, array, textBox1);`, все, внутри класса `one` (ужасное название) будут все эти объекты. Конструктор `public one() { }` убирайте, он вам в данном варианте только вредит. `один обьект One но серовно значения не передаются в массив Array` - вы не вчитываетесь в то, что я вам пишу. Я вам сказал, убрать конструктор без параметров, и сделать этот один объект, вы сделали обратное, убрали объект, создаваемый с параметрами, оставив пустой. Внимательней прочитайте то, что я вам писал, подумайте, а затем делайте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за объяснение, вот правлю код переписан, но возникла новая ошибка - пишет что "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

Comment: Ваш объект значит `NULL`, например, что будет, если ваш код не зайдет в `if (indic == true)`, верно, ваша `clasone` будет не инициализирована. У вас есть все возможные инструменты, чтоб это выяснить, например, пройдитесь по вашему коду шаг за шагом, посмотрите как и что там появляется, имеет-ли это нужный вам результат? Найдете очень много полезного. Также вон, зеленым должно подсвечивать, если в указанной строке возможет NULL, что сразу должно в голове рождать мыслю по типу "ага, значит это надо обработать, чтоб не получить ошибку".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо вам, код заработал с отладчиком (ошибка была!) "через объект clasone можно передать только методы но никак не отдельные переменные". Если можно хотел бы узнать разницу передачи через private one clasone; и без параметров one One= new one в моем случае; ?Я так понял они разные 1 - конструктор, 2 -  объект

Comment: Разница между `new one()` и `new one(..., ..., ...)`? Если да, то разницы нет, это все создание экземпляра класса с использование его конструктора, вы сами эти конструкторы у своего класса создали, где первый был `public one() { }`, а второй `public one(DataGridView dataGridView1, double[] array, TextBox textbox1){...}`, вызвав без параметров, вызывалась вся логика, что в `public one {}`, у вас она была пустая, ну а вызвав с параметрами, вызывалась логика другого конструктора, где вы сохраняли ссылку на нужные вам объекты внутри класса. Вот собственно и вся разница.

Comment: Теперь все ясно, Огромная благодарнасть вам за такие точные и открытые ответы, ни один учитель которых я встречал не отвечал так подробно, вы лучший!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе формы две переменные типа one: One и classone. array передаётся в classone, а дальше в форме используется One, а там пусто.